# DiscordJS Canvas silently fails. Why?

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord, discord.js, node-canvas

I've been learning the basics of creating a Discord bot and I've been trying to get a hang of using Canvas with DiscordJS.

I've tried to follow [this simple tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html#setting-up-canvas) but I just can't seem to get any leads on what could be wrong.

For reference, here is the point in the tutorial that I have gotten to.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Since the image takes time to load, you should await it
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
    // This uses the canvas dimensions to stretch the image onto the entire canvas
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Use helpful Attachment class structure to process the file for you
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, attachment);
});
```

When this functions triggers, it should cause the bot to send "Welcome to the server, [member name here]" as a message to the server plus the attachment specified.

However, instead of doing this, it just sends the message to the server with no attachment at all.

I get no errors when testing this either.

Could anyone give me some pointers on what could be going wrong here?

EDIT: After further experimenting, I have found a solution.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    console.log("Here we go");
    console.log(member.guild.name);
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'general');

    if (!channel) return;

    // Set a new canvas to the dimensions of 700x250 pixels
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(2097, 2097); //Works correctly
    // ctx (context) will be used to modify a lot of the canvas

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Since the image takes time to load, you should await it
    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./sadman.jpg'); //Finds it
    // This uses the canvas dimensions to stretch the image onto the entire canvas
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Use helpful Attachment class structure to process the file for you

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, { files: [{ attachment: canvas.toBuffer() }] });
});
```

Comment: How about a smaller canvas without no image just draw a rectangle in it? Does that work?

Comment: No, replacing the ctx.drawImage line with ```ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);``` leads to the same result.

Comment: when you debug does the `canvas.toBuffer()` has the correct value?

Comment: ...and they do have a github repo: https://github.com/discordjs/guide/tree/master/code-samples/popular-topics/canvas you can raise an issue there for support

Comment: I just tried your code with `ctx.fillRect` and it worked. Could you check if the bot is able to send images in that channel?

Comment: I have just confirmed that it can. I changed the channel.send line to ```channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, { files: ['./wallpaper.jpg'] });``` and it successfully sent the image.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely the fact that you didnt specify a valid image location at
`Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');` Does your image exactly match that name? Make sure your code can read that file in that directory

Comment: It is not this unfortunately. When I replace the path in Canvas.loadImage with one that doesn't exist, I get an error:

```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory './nonexistantFile.jpg'```

No error is present when I use a valid path name, yet it still fails to produce the image.